# Concatenating three strings in Python

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I have tried this several different ways, and I'm not sure why it's not working, o.value = test for this code.

```
for o in myParameterFile.parameter_list:
    if o.parameter == 'unique_project_name':
        lsfName = 'dip3d_' + o.value + '.bsub'
            print lsfName
```

output:
`.bsub_test`

expected output:
`dip3d_test.bsub`

So it's overwriting the initial part of the string `dip3d_` with `.bsub`
I have also tried putting the strings in a list and using `''.join()` with the same result.

I'm using python 2.7

Comment: There is no way for this code to produce this output. The output you've posted must be coming from some other part of your program.

Comment: Where's the rest of your script? Your output is not being generated by this part of the code. Are you sure what `o.parameter` is is correct?

Comment: Post the first part containing `myParameterFile`. If `o.value` is `'test'`, the output should be the expected one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a rough guess, the string `o.value` contains a carriage return character, and when you print it, you're overwriting the `dip3d` text.

Comment: Sounds about right.  Confirm with `print ' '.join( '%02X' % ord(ch) for ch in o.value )` and look for `0D` (the hex code for carriage return) in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough context to say why it's doing that, but you could try

```
lsfName = 'dip3d_{0}.bsub'.format(o.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an error in the parser that was including the carriage return '\r' char.

```
else:
        if char != '=' and char != '\n' and char != '\"' and != '\r':
            valueName.append(char)
```

Fixed the problem. It was a silly error. I need to modify their parser to ignore some other stuff too.